# Countif function not acting how I would expect

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, counter

So I have an excel function where I want to check to see if a string contains any of the strings mentioned, if it does, simply add 1 to the total, here's what I have:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:F2, "*offline")+COUNTIF(C2:F2, "*Expired")+COUNTIF(C2:F2, "*login")+COUNTIF(C2:F2, "*log in")
```

So for example if C2 says "login" D2 says "offline" , this function would only show "1".

Comment: Now we're clear on what you *expect*, and what you *tried*. It apparently didn't work as expected - but what happened instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples using just one `Countif`

If you want to count 1 then here is an example

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(C2:F2, {"*offline","*Expired","*login","*log in"}))>0,1,0)
```

If you want to count all instances then change the above formula to

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(C2:F2, {"*offline","*Expired","*login","*log in"}))
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, you don't really want a count, you just want to know if any of those cells have one of the values you're looking for?

Surround your function in an if statement and print 1 if it has a count at all.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C2:F2, "*offline")+COUNTIF(C2:F2, "*Expired")+COUNTIF(C2:F2, "*login")+COUNTIF(C2:F2, "*log in"),1,0)
```

Comment: Nope, I want a count of every cell between C2:F2, the issue for the moment is that it seems to only work properly for *offline and nothing else.   So let's say I have offline, login, expired, I'd want that to equal 3,  since it's 3 "bad" results.